# How to convert Mongodb query to Cakephp compatible

Tags: mongodb, cakephp-2.0

How to change mongodb command into cakephp script?

I have written this command:

```
db.citytable.find({
"city": "del%"
 }, {
"cityname": 1
});
```

I want to convert it in Cakephp. `like` does not work with Mongodb.
I am using Cakephp with MongoDB.

**EDIT**

```
public function load_city() {
    $this - > layout = false;
    $city_list = array();
    $this - > autoRender = false;
    if ($this - > request - > is('ajax')) {
        $city_term = strtoupper($this - > request - > query('term'));
        $mydb = new MongoClient();


        $params = array(
            'conditions' = > array(
            'OR' = > array(
            'local_area' = > new MongoRegex("/$city_term/i"),
            'city_name' = > new MongoRegex("/$city_term/i"), ), ), );
        $results = $this - > Managelist - > find('all', $params);
        $this - > set(compact('results'));
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $city_list[] = $result['Managelist']['local_area'].",".$result['Managelist']['city_name'];

            array_unshift($city_list, $result['Managelist']['city_name']);

        }

        echo json_encode(array_unique($city_list));

        exit;

    }
}
```

I am calling `load_city()` from my jquery autocomplete.

Comment: Try this plugin [https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb). Used it about a year ago with minimal effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $collection = $m->selectCollection($this->dbName, 'citytable');
    $string="del";
    $regexObj = new MongoRegex("/$string/i");
    $where = array("city" => $regexObj);
    $resultset = $collection->find($where);

    $resultData = array();
    while ($resultset->hasNext()) {
        $clientObj = $resultset->getNext();
        $resultData[] = $clientObj;
    }
    var_dump($resultData);
```

Comment: I has already solved that problem. Now can you tell me how to use `OR` operator in cakephp. I am using Mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

For the Or Clause use below code,

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$collection = $m->selectCollection($this->dbName, 'citytable');
$resultset = $collection->find(array('$or' => array(
  array("field1" => "test"),
  array("field2" => "data")
)));
```

Comment: I used this same syntax already. But blank response has come with jquery ui autocomplete.

Comment: I also used the same code. In my project and its working fine for me. Can you please share your code here. So I can check